# Cannot find the class from library project's jar when maven build my project

Tags: android, maven, jar, android-library, apklib

I have downloaded an 3rd party Android library project, the project contains no java class file but an **jar** file under `libs/` folder:

```
libs/
    - CustomService.jar
res/
   -…
pom.xml
```

This library project can be maven built to **apklib** archive. I built it & I have installed this archive into my **local maven repository**.

Then in my own Android project, I have added the dependency of this **apklib** project:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.custom.service</groupId>
   <artifactId>custom-service</artifactId>
   <type>apklib</type>
   <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

In my Java code, I have used the class from the **CustomService.jar** , but when I maven build my project I constantly get the following error:

```
[ERROR] package com.custom.service.user does not exist
[ERROR] location: class com.my.app.MyClass
[ERROR] /Users/Johon/MyApp/src/main/java/com/my/app/MyClass.java:[34,17] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable UserService
```

The above error complains that it cannot find the `UserService` class from the library apklib archive. Then, I checked the content of the library jar file by command:

`jar tf CustomService.jar`

I see that the class is in **CustomService.jar** of the library project

```
com/custom/service/user/UserService.class
```

This class is in the jar, Why I get the error then????

Comment: I doubt anyone can answer your question at this point, because almost everyone using gradle + .aar instead of maven + .apklib now.

Comment: apklib is deprecated. Try to generate aar file instead
http://simpligility.github.io/android-maven-plugin/aar.html
and then add dependency to aar

Comment: Could you please share your Maven logs about installation of Custom-service.jar to your local repository? It seems to me that dependency properties may be wrong.

Comment: Check your maven settings file. When you run from console it may be getting a different xml file.

Comment: Do you have access to the source file? You could might as well compile it!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add scope :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.custom.service</groupId>
   <artifactId>custom-service</artifactId>
   <type>apklib</type>
   <version>1.0</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

Comment: Compile scope is default in Maven, so adding it will have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is of type `apk` or any other type **compatible** with`apklib` libraries. Default `jar` type **will ignore** `apklib` dependencies.

```xml
<project>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
...
</project>
```